# Split a row into multiple rows

Tags: oracle

I have values as below.

```
ID  Attribute_Name  Operator    Value
--- --------------- --------    ---------------------
10  test1           In          ('ABC','BCD')
10  test2           =           0
10  test3           <>          11
10  test4           In          ('A1','A2','A3','A4')
11  test3           =           25
11  test4           In          ('B1','B2','B3')
12  test1           Not In      ('C1','C2','C3')
12  test2           =           120
12  test3           =           'D'
12  test4           <>          30
12  test5           In          ('E1','E2','E3')
```

I required the Oracle query result in below format.
I tried multiple ways but not getting in required format

```
ID    Result
---   ---------------------------------------------

10  test2=0~test3<>11~test1='ABC'~test4='A1'
10  test2=0~test3<>11~test1='ABC'~test4='A2'
10  test2=0~test3<>11~test1='ABC'~test4='A3'
10  test2=0~test3<>11~test1='ABC'~test4='A4'
10  test2=0~test3<>11~test1='BCD'~test4='A1'
10  test2=0~test3<>11~test1='BCD'~test4='A2'
10  test2=0~test3<>11~test1='BCD'~test4='A3'
10  test2=0~test3<>11~test1='BCD'~test4='A4'
11  test3=25~test4='B1'
11  test3=25~test4='B2'
11  test3=25~test4='B3'
12  test1<>'C1'~test2=120~test3='D'!test4<>30~test5='E1'
12  test1<>'C2'~test2=120~test3='D'!test4<>30~test5='E1'
12  test1<>'C3'~test2=120~test3='D'!test4<>30~test5='E1'
12  test1<>'C1'~test2=120~test3='D'!test4<>30~test5='E2'
12  test1<>'C2'~test2=120~test3='D'!test4<>30~test5='E2'
12  test1<>'C3'~test2=120~test3='D'!test4<>30~test5='E2'
12  test1<>'C1'~test2=120~test3='D'!test4<>30~test5='E3'
12  test1<>'C2'~test2=120~test3='D'!test4<>30~test5='E3'
12  test1<>'C3'~test2=120~test3='D'!test4<>30~test5='E3'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your effort. Recommended search: [split csv](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boracle%5D+split+csv+) and think about ordering - why is the `ID` 10  ordered as *test2, test3, test1, test4*?

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct t.id,t.attribute_name,replace(replace(t.operator,'Not In','<>'),'In','=') as operator,
                  replace(substr(replace(replace(value, ')', ''), '(', ''),
                         decode(level - 1,
                                0,
                                0,
                                instr(value, ',', 1, level - 1)),
                         (decode(level,
                                 regexp_count(value, ',') + 1,
                                 length(value) + 1,
                                 instr(value, ',', 1, level))) -
                         (decode(level - 1,
                                 0,
                                 0,
                                 instr(value, ',', 1, level - 1)) + 1)),',','') as result
    from test_tab t
  connect by level <= regexp_count(value, ',') + 1
   order by id, t.attribute_name
```

I create a table test_tab as yourtable,and this code can split value into  multiple rows.

But how to get the final result，I have no idea.